# runApp through application

Tags: r, shiny

I using ArcGIS system for spatial analysis. The system calling to R-script via "arcgisbinding" package.

I tried to Integrate into the R script command line which calling to "shiny" app. Something like:

```
 tool_exec <- function(in_param, out_param)

{…

runApp(appDir = '~/General/PROCESS/R/RB/newdir')

…}
```

As long as I run the script from R (I'm using R 3.2.5 32 bit with Rstudio) everything works well. But wean I'm performed the script from arcGIS Tool, I received the following message

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3519

and the process stopped (It looks to me like a kind of circular loop).

I did not found any relevant documentation to this error, do you know what is the problem?